# Secure Login with PHP

Tags: php, security, web

I've been searching around for a long time regarding secure login with PHP. I've found some interesting content, though I'm still not entirely positive on the most secure and simplistic approach.

I've created a simple system, though I'm unsure where it's secure enough. I'll keep this brief as not to smother you with details:

My user table in the database contains a column named "*loginToken*". When the user logs in, a  value is created(*based upon that user's id, a random number, and finally sha1 hashed*), which is inserted into loginToken of the database user table.

In addition to that, a $_CCOKIE is created with the same value. So these values are completely different to each user, and alternates each time the user logs in.

Now to check the user is logged in, I use this following code:

```
$user_id = -1; //By default, the user is logged out

if (isset($_SESSION["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["ut"])) { //Check session and user token exists
    //Get variables
    $uid = $_SESSION["user"]; //Get user ID
    $ut = $_COOKIE["ut"]; //Get user token

    //Compare the user id with the user token in the database
    $sql = mysql_query("
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `id` = '$uid' AND `login_token` = '$ut'
    ");

    //Get result
    $sql = mysql_result($sql, 0);

    //Found!
    if ($sql == 1) {
        $user_id = $uid; //User logged in!
    }
}
```

Is that understandable? If so, is that a secure enough method?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not secure at all. You're not sanitising your inputs and you're trusting everything from the client. Use prepared statements at least, please.

Comment: you need to look at mysqli and parameterized queries http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @RudiVisser : Sorry, I'm still rather new to this area of coding. What are "prepared statements"?

Comment: You will almost certainly get better results by using an existing, well-reviewed system. Authentication systems that have been scrutinized by many developers will usually have fewer bugs and better security than one developed in isolation.

Comment: As you are new, it'll be easier for you to pick up the better database API, go to php.net and search for MySQLi or PDO. These use prepared statements

Comment: @TomMcPadden: look into Symfony or some other recent PHP framework, e.g. FuelPHP, Laravel, etc. Pick one and embrace it, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not secure. A user could set a malicious cookie, that can do SQL injection on your database.

Use a session variable.

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === true) { ...
```

This is frequently used method.

Generally you want the user to type in username and password over HTTPS secured form. When you receive the request, compare the username, and the hashed version of the password you store in the database, to the hash version supplied by the form. If the hashes match, set $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true.

Later in your code, check that session variable to ensure the user is logged in.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misunderstood. I understand how to login, but the script is used at the start of every page to check wherever the user is currently logged in.
EDIT: And since sessions only last for a limited duration, I can't rely soely on sessions.

Comment: Sessions can be implemented to last forever. They are implemented via a cookie. You can alter PHPs handling of sessions, which is common in order to use a SQL-based back-end for session data which is more secure and more scalable.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. Thank you! Is there any way a user could manipulate a session to login as another user though?

Comment: Yes that would be called session hijacking. Your session "key" should be difficult to guess so its not really a problem. There are techniques to get around that it may not be worth it however.